# How to use ng-click in Angular ui-tree for drag and drop as well as performing some function

Tags: angularjs, drag-and-drop

**My Angular code**

```
<div ui-tree="rootTree" data-drag-enabled="false">
  <ol ui-tree-nodes="" ng-model="course.sections" ng-class="{hidden: collapsed}">
    <li ng-repeat="section in course.sections" ui-tree-node> <div ui-tree-handle class="tree-node tree-node-content" ng-click="editSection(section)" >
      <a class="btn btn-success btn-xs"ng-if="section.sectionInstances && section.sectionInstances.length > 0" data-nodrag ng-click="toggle(this)">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-down" ng-class="{'glyphicon-chevron-right': collapsed,'glyphicon-chevron-down': !collapsed }">
        </span>
      </a>
     {{section.sec_name}}
     <a class="pull-right btn btn-danger btn-xs" data-nodrag ng-click="removeSection(section)">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove">
        </span>
     </a>
     <a class="pull-right btn btn-primary btn-xs" data-nodrag ng-click="addSectionInstance(section)" style="margin-right: 8px;">
        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus">
        </span>
     </a>
      </div>
    </li>
  </ol>
</div>
```

---

If i use `data-drag-enabled="false"`, then `ng-click function` is calling. I want both the function drag and drop as well as `ng-clik function`.

Comment: Are you just needing to trigger a function when the `drag-start` occurs, or when you simply click on the node?

Answer (score 0):

If you are just wanting to perform functionality on 'dragStart', then it appears according to the [angular-ui-tree documentation](https://github.com/angular-ui-tree/angular-ui-tree#eventParam), that you can define `treeOptions` in your controller and assign them to your tree directive attribute value.

```
myAppModule.controller('MyController', function($scope) {
  $scope.treeOptions = {
    dragStart: function(sourceNodeScope, destNodesScope, destIndex) {
      // Do things here 
    },
    dragEnd: function(sourceNodeScope, destNodesScope, destIndex) {
    }
  };
});

<div ui-tree="treeOptions">
  <ol ui-tree-nodes ng-model="nodes">
    <li ng-repeat="node in nodes" ui-tree-node>{{node.title}}</li>
  </ol>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

same trouble here, few years after.
Sean answer doesn't seem to answer the question.

issue: 
* with drag n drop enable: I can't use ng-click to remove/edit a node, but I can drag n drop it.
* w/o drag n drop enable: my ng-click works.

Solution: 
move the "ui-tree-handle" from the global div to specific location w/o any ng-click in.